# Getting TypeError using Angular2 AoT ngc compiler with RC5

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to compile my program using the Ahead of Time ngc compiler.  I haven't used ngc in the past but I've followed several examples on blogs which make it look fairly straight forward.  My code runs fine in the browser and the typescript compiler compiles it fine but I get the following error when I use ngc.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
at maybeGetSimpleFunction (node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\src\collector.js:28:41)
at node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\src\collector.js:227:41
at visitEachNode (node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:8154:30)
at Object.forEachChild (node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:8314:24)
at MetadataCollector.getMetadata (node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\src\collector.js:189:12)
at ReflectorHost.getMetadataFor (node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\reflector_host.js:217:43)
at StaticReflector.getModuleMetadata (node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\static_reflector.js:478:40)
at CodeGenerator.readFileMetadata (node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.js:33:51)
at node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.js:91:74
at Array.map (native)
Compilation failed
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which ngc command you ran? Do you see NgFactory files for your each component and module? Can you share your main.ts file?

Comment: ngc -p ./src where src is where my htm, tsconfig and angular2 app live.  So basically ran ngc with the same options I'm using for tsc.  No factory files have been generated.

Comment: My typescript files and javascript files are living side by side.  Am I wrong thinking that ngc only cares about the typescript files?

Comment: Once you ran `ngc -p ./src` command it should generates a new file for each component and module ( called an NgFactory ). Have you installed these - `npm install @angular/compiler-cli typescript@next @angular/platform-server @angular/compiler` ?

Comment: I've installed those.  I've run through this.
https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/%40angular/compiler-cli

Comment: I've even added 
    constructor(appRef: ApplicationRef) {
        appRef.bootstrap(AppComponent);
    }
to my main app module class.

Comment: i am starting for AoT on angular 2 rc5, i am getting version errors when trying to install compiler/cli
can you suggest me a post or blog to refer